# How to make the system crash using a faulty kernel module - FC19?

Tags: c, kernel, fedora, kernel-module

As per my knowledge, the linux kernel is monolithic. It means if any kernel module crashes, the entire system should crash. However, I didn't see the same. Here is my buggy program?
Why my machine didn't crash? How can I amend my program to make my system crash?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h> /** needed by all modules **/
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /** This is for KERN_ALERT **/

MODULE_LICENSE("SJ BSD/GPL");

int t = 100;

static int hello_init(void)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello SJ\n");
  t = t *10;
   t = t/0;
   printk(KERN_ALERT "The value of t is %d\n",t);
  return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye..SJ\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

This is the output I get -

```
# insmod ./hello.ko
Segmentation fault

#uname -a
2.6.32.26-175.fc12.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed Dec 1 21:45:50 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

The dmesg tail is

```
id: 20883, comm: insmod Tainted: P           (2.6.32.26-175.fc12.i686.PAE #1) OptiPlex 990
EIP: 0060:[<f7e9e02f>] EFLAGS: 00010246 CPU: 4
EIP is at param_init+0x1a/0x27 [param]
EAX: 00000000 EBX: f7e9e0b0 ECX: c0aa8e60 EDX: 00000000
ESI: 00000000 EDI: f7e9e015 EBP: f2d39f84 ESP: f2d39f7c
 DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Process insmod (pid: 20883, ti=f2d38000 task=f6630000 task.ti=f2d38000)
Stack:
 f7e9e079 00000000 f2d39f9c c040305b 00000000 f7e9e0b0 00000000 bfe0ed78
<0> f2d39fac c04716da 09932018 00000000 f2d38000 c040903b 09932018 000169c9
<0> 09932008 00000000 bfe0ed78 bfe0ed98 00000080 0000007b 0000007b 00000000
Call Trace:
 [<c040305b>] ? do_one_initcall+0x51/0x13f
 [<c04716da>] ? sys_init_module+0xac/0x1e2
 [<c040903b>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
Code: 1f 44 00 00 68 66 e0 e9 f7 e8 cf 93 90 c8 58 c9 c3 55 89 e5 0f 1f 44 00 00 ff 35 18 e2 e9 f7 68 79 e0 e9 f7 e8 b4 93 90 c8 31 c0 <c7> 05 00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 c9 c3 90 04 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 
EIP: [<f7e9e02f>] param_init+0x1a/0x27 [param] SS:ESP 0068:f2d39f7c
```

I expect the entire system to crash. However, the machine has not crashed or rebooted. It's just that particular module has crashed. I want to make the entire system down. It should be ideally since the kernel is monolithic. Any problem  in kernel should shutdown the entire the machine. However, I am not seeing the same. What is the issue? can you please throw some light on it? Is my concept not correct here?

Comment: Are you just using `sudo insmod` to put this module in? And have you verified that it actually loaded?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `dmesg | tail` after you insert the module?

Comment: Please also provide the output of `uname -a` and `dmesg | tail`.

Comment: See my updated answer. Unfortunately, without looking at the kernel source code, this is pure speculation. I have suggested an experiment in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the old way of doing the writing the functions and it reliably crashed my VM's kernel.

The VM is running `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3`.

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */



int t = 100;
int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello SJ\n");
    t = t *10;
    t = t/0;
    printk(KERN_ALERT "The value of t is %d\n",t);
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
```

Based on your update, my best guess is that the `insmod` tool is compiling and running the functions before inserting them into the kernel, which is why the `insmod` command itself segfaults. The reason is that your `dmesg` output suggests that it is `Process insmod` which has segfaulted. To verify this though, you would have to look at the `insmod` source code for your system.

An interesting experiment to determine whether `insmod` is running the module in kernel mode or user mode, would be to put some privileged instruction (such as `rdmsr`) as inline assembler into the module and see if `insmod` will choke on that.

Comment: It didn't crash in my case. I could see a crash but not a system crash and a shutdown or reboot.